# find word within line of lines in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I (New to Haskell ) want to find if a word in line (of lines) is present or not. I saw few functions to achieve it like : elem, isInfixOf

```
Prelude DL> isInfixOf "new" "I am new to Haskell"
True

Prelude DL> elem "new" ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]
False
```

How can I implement 'isInfixOf' on every string within list of strings.

Comment: What is your expected return type? A list of bools telling telling if the string is an infix of each string in the list?

Comment: Minor stylistic note, `isInfixOf` is usually used... well, infix (not because it is talking about infix things, but because of how it works grammatically).  So you'd usually see ``"new" `isInfixOf` "I am new to Haskell"``.  And in the case of the answers, you might see it used as a section, e.g. ``any ("new" `isInfixOf`) [...]``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expect to get true:

```
any (isInfixOf "new") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell too!"]
```

If you want a list of Bool:

```
map (isInfixOf "new") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell too!"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You do this by mapping the `isInfixOf` function over a list of `Strings` like so:

```
ghci>> map (isInfixOf "new") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]
[False, True, False]
```

`map` evaluates the predicate for each element in the list.

Building from this, you can use other functions from `Data.List` to find out more about the list as a whole:

```
ghci>> any (isInfixOf "new") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]
True
ghci>> all (isInfixOf "new") ["I am", "new to", "Haskell"]
False
```